# Google Cloud Storage API write files with special characters vs regular python files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, character-encoding, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google App Engine to write a new file to a Google Cloud Storage bucket for eventual serving in the browser. Normally on my local computer this writes a nice text file which I can open and see the test character as expected:

```
with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(u'é'.encode('utf-8'))
```

When I open `new_file.txt` in Notepad it's properly displayed as `é`.

But when I try the analogous process on Google Cloud Storage:

```
with gcs.open('/mybucket/newfile.txt', 'w', content_type='text/html') as f:
    f.write(u'é'.encode('utf-8'))
```

My files are served in the browser with special characters all messed up, in this case it outputs `Ã©`.

[image]

Comment: Can you try setting `content_type='text/html; charset=utf-8'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default charset for HTTP 1.1 is  ISO-8859-1.

If you want the browser to interpret your text as UTF-8, you should set the content-type header to include the charset, like this:

```
with gcs.open('/mybucket/newfile.txt', 'w', content_type='text/html; charset=utf-8') as f:
```

Comment: That did it, the file now serves from my bucket with the special characters the way I expect them to show. Thank you very much!