# Outputting other languages to Cloud Pub/Sub topics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-translate, google-cloud-pubsub, vision-api

I'm using Google Cloud Functions in conjunction with their Vision API and Translate API to extract text from images and then translate the extracted text into various languages. The output is passed to a Pub/Sub topic and then stored in a Cloud Storage bucket. All the components appear to be working fine, except my output is not properly encoded for the language, so  I'm getting strings like "PÃ¢tÃ© Oeufs Mimosa" rather than "Pâté – Oeufs Mimosa".

Here's the relevant code I'm using:

```
# [START functions_ocr_detect]
def detect_text(bucket, filename):
    print('Looking for text in image {}'.format(filename))

    futures = []

    text_detection_response = vision_client.text_detection({
        'source': {'image_uri': 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket, filename)}
    })
    annotations = text_detection_response.text_annotations
    if len(annotations) > 0:
        text = annotations[0].description
    else:
        text = ''
    print('Extracted text {} from image ({} chars).'.format(text, len(text)))

    detect_language_response = translate_client.detect_language(text)
    src_lang = detect_language_response['language']
    print('Detected language {} for text {}.'.format(src_lang, text))

    # Submit a message to the bus for each target language
    for target_lang in TO_LANG:
        topic_name = TRANSLATE_TOPIC
        if src_lang == target_lang or src_lang == 'und':
            topic_name = RESULT_TOPIC
        message = {
            'text': text,
            'filename': filename,
            'lang': target_lang,
            'src_lang': src_lang
        }
        message_data = json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')
        topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)
        future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=message_data)
        futures.append(future)
    for future in futures:
        future.result()
# [END functions_ocr_detect]


# [START message_validatation_helper]
def validate_message(message, param):
    var = message.get(param)
    if not var:
        raise ValueError('{} is not provided. Make sure you have \
                          property {} in the request'.format(param, param))
    return var
# [END message_validatation_helper]


# [START functions_ocr_process]
def process_image(file, context):
    """Cloud Function triggered by Cloud Storage when a file is changed.
    Args:
        file (dict): Metadata of the changed file, provided by the triggering
                                 Cloud Storage event.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata of triggering event.
    Returns:
        None; the output is written to stdout and Stackdriver Logging
    """
    bucket = validate_message(file, 'bucket')
    name = validate_message(file, 'name')

    detect_text(bucket, name)

    print('File {} processed.'.format(file['name']))
# [END functions_ocr_process]


# [START functions_ocr_translate]
def translate_text(event, context):
    if event.get('data'):
        message_data = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
        message = json.loads(message_data)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Data sector is missing in the Pub/Sub message.')

    text = validate_message(message, 'text')
    filename = validate_message(message, 'filename')
    target_lang = validate_message(message, 'lang')
    src_lang = validate_message(message, 'src_lang')

    print('Translating text into {}.'.format(target_lang))
    translated_text = translate_client.translate(text,
                                                 target_language=target_lang,
                                                 source_language=src_lang)
    topic_name = RESULT_TOPIC']
    message = {
        'text': translated_text['translatedText'],
        'filename': filename,
        'lang': target_lang,
    }
    message_data = json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)
    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=message_data)
    future.result()
# [END functions_ocr_translate]


# [START functions_ocr_save]
def save_result(event, context):
    if event.get('data'):
        message_data = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
        message = json.loads(message_data)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Data sector is missing in the Pub/Sub message.')

    text = validate_message(message, 'text')
    filename = validate_message(message, 'filename')
    lang = validate_message(message, 'lang')

    print('Received request to save file {}.'.format(filename))

    bucket_name = RESULT_BUCKET
    result_filename = '{}_{}.txt'.format(filename, lang)
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(result_filename)

    print('Saving result to {} in bucket {}.'.format(result_filename, bucket_name))
    blob.upload_from_string(text)

    print('File saved.')
# [END functions_ocr_save]
```

Comment: This is an encoding problem. What/where is your output? How are you reading your output? Somewhere you are processing your strings as ASCII instead of UTF-8. Providing some debug output with your source will help us see the issue.

Comment: It outputs to a Cloud Pub/Sub topic and then that goes to a Cloud Storage bucket. See the translate_text() and save_result() function. I do have encoding set to UTF-8 wherever I could, i.e., `message_data = json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')` but somehow its converting to ASCII. I suspect it might be in the final save_result() where it stores the translation in Cloud Storage with the blob() function. Not sure how to add encoding there.

Comment: I do not see anything obvious except for maybe `var = message.get(param)`. Add debug code (log a message) each step you process/convert a string. This will show you where the string is converted to Ascii.

Comment: Note: I am assuming you are using Python 3. This makes a big difference.

Comment: Yes, Python 3.7. I'll see if I can figure out where it's happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Storage API write files with special characters vs regular python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004673/google-cloud-storage-api-write-files-with-special-characters-vs-regular-python-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [blob / object](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html) features a `content_encoding`, `content_type` and `content_language` header... which probably should be: `content_type='text/plain'; charset='utf-8', content_encoding='utf-8', content_language='fr'`.

Comment: Thanks, Martin - following your suggestion I was able to add the following to my save_results() function and got the output I wanted: ```    theHeader = f"content_type='text/plain'; charset='utf-8'; content_lang='{lang}'"
    blob.upload_from_string(text, theHeader)
```